# How to encode special chars in MMS SMIL XML

Tags: xml, encoding, special-characters, mms, smil

I am sending MMS messages containing text and image. This works well, but when the message text in the SMIL file contains special chars like Norwegian ÆØÅ it does not encode correctly. This is my SMIL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www/w3.org/2000/SMIL20/Language">
<head>
<layout>
<region id="Image" top="0" left="0" height="300" width="500"/>
<region id="Text" top="50" left="0" height="300" width="500"/>
</layout>
</head>
<body>
<par>
<img region="Image" src="20121002-144236.jpg" />
<text region="Text" src="20121002-144236.txt" />
</par>
</body>
</smil>
```

The file 20121002-144236.txt contains special chars.
Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Use the type attribute to specify the MIME type and the character set:

```
<text region="Text" src="20121002-144236.txt" type="text/plain; charset=UTF-8" />
```

If that fails, open the text file and save it as UTF-8 as well.